# Webservice method not found by JQuery Ajax-Request error 500

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

JS:

```
function showComments(couponId) {
            var jsontxt = JSON.stringify({ couponId });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<% =Page.ResolveUrl("~/Admin/UserCoupons.aspx/GetComments") %>",
                data: jsontxt,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                //async:true,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });

        }
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetComments(string couponId)
        {
            //will return precomipled generated html for display in div
            return "Success";

        }
```

The C# code is in page's code behind .cs file
i have solved this all before using stack over flow
thanks to experts here.
but this time there is some thing else

i am getting my debug pointer in page_load method then in master page's page load method. but debug doesn't enters to the GetComments

and getting exception

> Unknown web method GetComments.
>   Parameter name: methodName

Below is the stackTrace

```
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.CreateHandler(WebServiceData webServiceData, String methodName)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.CreateHandler(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ couponId });` makes no sense.... You would have `{ "foo" }`

Comment: @Sadiqabbas Hirani try this var jsontxt = JSON.stringify({ couponId: val }); //value need to pass in val and couponId is a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long google and all others and applying every possible solutions. finally, i found a solution. and that's 
edit the file at ~/App_start/RouteConfig.cs

replace

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

with

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

this solved my problem. any ways thanks to all who took interest and showed their generosity.

Answer (score 0):

Your data in ajax should be **JSON.stringify({ couponId:'123' })** //parameter name & value.

```
function showComments(couponId) {
            var jsontxt = JSON.stringify({ couponId:'123' });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<% =Page.ResolveUrl("~/Admin/UserCoupons.aspx/GetComments") %>",
                data: jsontxt,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                //async:true,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: couponId i am getting as a parameter

Comment: and also i am already getting
"{"couponId":"123"}" as value of jsontxt